# Out of range error in GRU Algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I use GRU algorithm which I downloaded it from the link:
https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm 
but when I run this algorithm i have the following error:

```
sentences = itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode("utf-8").lower()) for x in reader])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this is the part of the algorithm that has error in GRU implementation

```
# Split full comments into sentences 
sentences = itertools.chain(*[nltk.sent_tokenize(x[0].decode("utf-8").lower()) for x in reader])
```

Comment: Can you share your input file? What's `x` ? Most probably it has nothing to do with the code but what's in your data.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with GRU. Error is thrown because whatever is `reader`, it should be a list of singletons, meaning that there exists `reader[0][0]` and it simply does not. Check your data, as it is the issue.

Comment: The code exactly copy from the original and i checked the data and reader both of them have value but i could not find the problem